# Functional change of genital organs

Tags: science-based, biology

Let's see if I can explain my thoughts accurately with an example.

Imagine that a mad scientist decides to kidnap a few men and women and decides, just for fun, to switch their sexual organs, but not like the sex-change operations that exist nowadays: extracting the whole bulk of the male's reproductive system (not just penis and testicles, but the internal area as well) and implanting it on a female (I'm still considering whether the "vice-versa" bit should happen). 
Is it possible:

1. for the female to have their new organs functioning?
2. assuming 1) is possible, to have them work in a way that pleasure and ejaculation for the female is possible?

(Ho-boy... *facepalms*)

Comment: My "Writer" self tells me to answer you: "Hand wave it as possible and enjoy describing the erotica/porn aspects of it." And my geek self tells me to answer: "It is impossible, because everything is connected in the body"

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that, iirc, there was once an experiment performed where the testes from one monkey were attached to another, and remained functional. Presumably, the full-on genital transplant you described seems like it would effectively be a more complex version of that. How this would interact with nerves and sensations, I have no idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll approach this from what is perhaps a surprising angle.

**[Head transplants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_transplant) have been done.**

It is of course not quite as simple as no one has actually succeeded in connecting the spinal cord in a way that allows the head to control the body in any way.

There has been [quite a bit of research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_transplant#Current_Developments) however. And according to one expert in 2013, *the possibility exists to re-fuse a severed cord by use of [fusogens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell-cell_fusogens).* How exactly this will pan out is far beyond my medical knowledge, but it doesn't seem entirely unlikely that this will be possible in the future.

So what we have now is a male head with a female body and vice versa. From there on, it seems like a question of exchanging more (not too difficult to transplant) parts until you are happy to say that the your subject looks like a man with a functional female reproduction system rather than the head of a man on the body of a woman.

A hormone treatment additionally to what the sex organs produce themselves will likely be necessary to keep the female reproduction system functional (luckily this will also help with [lactation](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/strange-but-true-males-can-lactate/).

**Sexual stimulation**

As for sexual stimulation, [A clitoris is essentially the same as a penis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitoris#Clitoral_and_penile_similarities_and_differences)<sup>[citation needed]</sup>, with the same nerves leading to it. So after connecting the spinal cord, stimulating the penis should then for a female create similar reactions as the clitoris once did. It's not clear if the reaction of the brain will actually trigger an ejaculation though. much is still unclear about the female orgasm. And I don't Believe anyone has bothered to find out if a female brain knows how to make a male body ejaculate (though come to think of it...). That being said, the brain can adapt to almost anything, and I believe that claiming the reaction of the female brain to sexual stimulation is similar enough to a man's to trigger ejaculation won't stretch anyone's imagination.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... sure. Wont be an easy game, but possible for sure.

The surgery (except the nerve cells) is not the big problem. Just put it in and it's fine.... lol. Not really, but this is by far the easiest part.

A bigger issue will be the nerves. You surely heard about brain-surgeries today. They still are very complicated. Also to reattach lost extremities is easy, when you omit the nerve-connections. But if you want to give the patient the ability to use his extremities like in old days, it's still a hard job.
But if your mad scientist(which is more a mad doctor) can handle that, the pleasure will be there.

Second big issue is the hormone thing.
Transgender people often take hormones to change their sex (plus surgery of course). This takes many years. I know of one man that once was a woman. He took 6 years of therapy until he grew a beard, if you know what I mean.

Comment: The sex organs produce the hormones, so attaching male sex organs will increase testosterone in the body.